# Splitting a comma-delimited string of integers

Tags: c, string, arduino

My background is not in C (it's in Real Studio - similar to VB) and I'm really struggling to split a comma-delimited string since I'm not used to low-level string handling.

I'm sending strings to an Arduino over serial.  These strings are commands in a certain format.  For instance:

```
@20,2000,5!
@10,423,0!
```

'@' is the header indicating a new command and '!' is the terminating footer marking the end of a command.  The first integer after '@' is the command id and the remaining integers are data (the number of integers passed as data may be anywhere from 0 - 10 integers).

I've written a sketch that gets the command (stripped of the '@' and '!') and calls a function called `handleCommand()` when there is a command to handle.  The problem is, I really don't know how to split this command up to handle it!

Here's the sketch code:

```
String command; // a string to hold the incoming command
boolean commandReceived = false; // whether the command has been received in full

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // main loop
  handleCommand();
}

void serialEvent(){
  while (Serial.available()) {
  // all we do is construct the incoming command to be handled in the main loop

    // get the incoming byte from the serial stream
    char incomingByte = (char)Serial.read();

    if (incomingByte == '!')
    {
       // marks the end of a command
       commandReceived = true;
       return;
    }
    else if (incomingByte == '@')
    {
       // marks the start of a new command
       command = "";
       commandReceived = false;
       return;
    }
    else
    {
      command += incomingByte;
      return;
    }

  }
}

void handleCommand() {

  if (!commandReceived) return; // no command to handle

  // variables to hold the command id and the command data
  int id;
  int data[9];

  // NOT SURE WHAT TO DO HERE!!

  // flag that we've handled the command 
  commandReceived = false;
}
```

Say my PC sends the Arduino the string "@20,2000,5!".  My sketch ends up with a String variable (called `command`) that contains "20,2000,5" and the `commandRecieved` boolean variable is set to True so the `handleCommand()` function is called.

What I would like to do in the (currently useless) `handleCommand()` function is assign 20 to a variable called `id` and 2000 and 5 to an array of integers called `data`, i.e: `data[0] = 2000`, `data[1] = 5`, etc.

I've read about `strtok()` and `atoi()` but frankly I just can't get my head around them and the concept of pointers.  I'm sure my Arduino sketch could be optimised too.

Comment: those 2 are are a good method to do this. you could also try sscanf if it's avaliable

Comment: Could you provide any sample code?  I've struggled to come up with the C code in the above sketch.  I really don't know how to use the two methods I mentioned...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're using the Arduino core `String` type, `strtok` and other `string.h` functions aren't appropriate. Note that you **can** change your code to use standard C null-terminated strings instead, but using Arduino `String` will let you do this without using pointers.

The [`String`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject) type gives you [`indexOf`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringIndexOf) and [`substring`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringSubstring).

Assuming a String with the `@` and `!` stripped off, finding your command and arguments would look something like this:

```
// given: String command
int data[MAX_ARGS];
int numArgs = 0;

int beginIdx = 0;
int idx = command.indexOf(",");

String arg;
char charBuffer[16];

while (idx != -1)
{
    arg = command.substring(beginIdx, idx);
    arg.toCharArray(charBuffer, 16);

    // add error handling for atoi:
    data[numArgs++] = atoi(charBuffer);
    beginIdx = idx + 1;
    idx = command.indexOf(",", beginIdx);
}

data[numArgs++] = command.substring(beginIdx);
```

This will give you your entire command in the `data` array, including the command number at `data[0]`, while you've specified that only the args should be in `data`. But the necessary changes are minor.

Comment: Worked for me, but I had to adjust the last line to:
`
    arg = command.substring(beginIdx);
    arg.toCharArray(charBuffer, 16);
    data[numArgs] = atoi(charBuffer);`

Answer (score -1):

seems to work, could be buggy:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
char string[]="20,2000,5";
int a,b,c;
sscanf(string,"%i,%i,%i",&a,&b,&c);
printf("%i %i %i\n",a,b,c);
a=b=c=0;
a=atoi(strtok(string,","));
b=atoi(strtok(0,","));
c=atoi(strtok(0,","));
printf("%i %i %i\n",a,b,c);

return 0;
}
```