# Receive string from processing to arduino

Tags: java, arduino, processing

I want to receive a string from processing to arduino. I am writing a string(Basically an array of single digits in the form of string eg: <0213> is an array: 0 2 1 3). I am able to write it to port but how do I receive it on arduino? Following code is to send to arduino.

```
int[] send={0,2,3,1};
myPort =new Serial(this,"/dev/ttyACM0", 9600);
String theStg = "<" + nf(send[0], 3) +
                   " " + nf(send[1], 3) +
                   " " + nf(send[2], 3) +
                   " " + nf(send[3], 3) +
                   ">";
myPort.write(theStg);
```

Comment: http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/read, http://www.varesano.net/blog/fabio/serial-communication-arduino-and-processing-simple-examples-and-arduino-based-gamepad-int

Answer (score 0):

if you were using a string of char*, rather than the String Class, then you could use [avrlibc's strtok()](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__string.html#ga6ace85338eafe22a0ff52c00eb9779b8) command.

This has been addressed [previously(click here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915914/splitting-a-comma-delimited-string-of-integers-c-arduino)

And [here is a nice function](https://github.com/despild/SplitStringExample/blob/master/SplitStringExample.ino) you can simply add to your code to do the equivalent of the strtok(), but on a String object.